# Change css onfocus / on blur of input field

Tags: css

I currently have a piece of code that adds the adds / hides the word 'Search' on an input field.

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="q"  title="Search" class="input-search"  value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';  }" />
```

What I would like to do is add one more component to the mix. That is, if the word 'Search' is visible. I would like the color to be: #ccc. If a value has been entered I would like it to be #000; though I am just not sure how to make it and still maintain the existing onfocus / onblur functions.

Comment: why not use "placeholder" attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

 and use css to change color of the placeholder: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Comment: placeholder is new in html and some of old browsers like IE9 and IE8 and some versions of other browser does not support but it's a good practice to use placeholder attribute in new browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with CSS:

```
.input-search{
    color:#CCC;
}
.input-search:focus{
    color:#000;
}
```